# Custom Login Page for SharePoint Online Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sp-online

Is it possible to create custom login page for SharePoint online(I don't want to brand the page). I need custom page so that I can add additional field other than username and password and passing user selected input to site home page. I see old threads that it is not possible, however wanted to validate in 2019 if we have any option now?

Any other recommended option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't control the login process or any part of it. And that's a good thing because you don't want to be on the hook when things break.

You'll need to find another way to pass your data to the home page.